# Snowflake materialized view on external tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The documentation says that I will be able to see a separate warehouse MATERIALIZED_VIEW_MAINTENANCE for MV maintenance, if I am an accountadmin. I created a materialized view over an external table and waited for more than a hour, but I could not see this warehouse under usage section

> Snowsight As a user with the proper privileges, click on Admin »
> Usage.
>
> Classic Console As an account administrator, click on Account Account
> tab » Billing & Usage.
>
> The credit costs are tracked in a Snowflake-provided virtual warehouse
> named Snowflake logo in blue (no text) MATERIALIZED_VIEW_MAINTENANCE.

Comment: Are you sure you've followed all of the steps needed to automatically refresh the external table for the materialized view?  Have you queried the materialized_view_refresh_history in account_usage to see if your MV has been refreshed?

Comment: Yes, the below query gives me the credit usage                                              
  select *
  from table(information_schema.materialized_view_refresh_history(
    date_range_start=>'2023-03-31 19:00:00.000',
    date_range_end=>'2023-04-02 11:49:00.000'));

Comment: That query is from information_schema, where as I believe the UI that you were asking about relate to account_usage.  Either way, it shows that it is refreshing, so you should see it in both places, assuming you have the right privileges to account_usage.